# How to use libphonenumber.phone_number_util in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

To parse phone number I need to use `libphonenumber.phone_number_util` in my controller ( Symfony 4) as like as :

```
$parsed = $this->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->parse($phoneNo);
```

as we have `libphonenumber.phone_number_util` in private I wanted to make it public by adding this helper in service as below:

```
services:
   libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil:
      alias: libphonenumber.phone_number_util
      public: true
```

But this returns `Exception` and message:

```
"message": "The \"libphonenumber.phone_number_util\" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this in a controller method (which I presume you do based on `$this->get(...)`), you need to

1) Declare your *controller* as a service and tag it with `controller.service_arguments` tag

2) Make sure your util service id matches the class name (I suppose it does already). You don't need it to be public - that's and ancient approach

3) Require the util as a parameter to your controller's action method.

E.g.

```
services:
    libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil:
        alias: libphonenumber.phone_number_util

    AppBundle\Controller\MyController:
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

and

```
public function validatePhoneAction(Request $request, PhoneNumberUtil $phoneNumberUtil)
{
    ...
    $phoneNumberUtil->parse($request->request->get('phone_number');
    ...
}
```

There is a nice Symfony blog post about these changes in dependency management: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default